# Why is my bash script not exporting to my environment?

Tags: bash, export, environment-variables

I have a simple little bash script that will ask for a password and export it to the environment:

```
printf "Proxy authentication failed.\n"
read -p "Enter Password to try again: " mypassword
printf "Proxy authentication succeeded\n"
export PASSWORD="mypassword"
```

However when I try to run it, it will not export to the environment:

```
baal@baal-Aspire-5733Z:/tmp$ sh vaWfKh.sh
Proxy authentication failed.
Enter Password to try again: test
Proxy authentication succeeded
baal@baal-Aspire-5733Z:/tmp$ printenv
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;
...
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
PATH=/home/baal/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/baal/.rvm/bin:/home/baal/.rvm/bin
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

How can I export to an environment variable via a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `source` the script or run `.` in front of it in order to export a variable during the script -

Note: you need to interpolate your `mypassword` variable in order to set it to your environmental variable.

Let's say this is your `./myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Proxy authentication failed.\n"
read -p "Enter Password to try again: " mypassword
printf "Proxy authentication succeeded\n"
export PASSWORD=${mypassword}
```

In your terminal run either:

```
. ./myscript.sh
```

Or

```
source ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: @arm67146 Did you try updating your script to include the interpolation? I tested this updated script locally and it worked for me.

Comment: Hey, yeah I figured it out, I'm calling it through another application and the path was getting messed up. Thank you it works!

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped.